# Send 2 inputs to a program which has 2 fgets

Tags: linux, shell, execution

I have a program which is first asking for a username, and then, after checking it, asks for a password.

Those two request are made with `fgets` function in the program.

I'm trying to execute this program by sending it username and password, in one command line.

Example: `cat /tmp/credentials | ./program`

So I just want to execute and connect with one command line.
I'm running it on Ubuntu.

Comment: OK; that should work.  What happens?  Why are you needing to ask a question on SO?  You could avoid the pipeline with `./program < /tmp/credentials`; that should work too.  Does the program read anything else from standard input?

Comment: nope, I'm juste wondering how to send my credentials, how to parse them. for example, am I good if in /tmp/credentials, it is : username\npassword ? The program is reading, one time for username, then another time for password. When I try to check what's in the first buffer, it shows username AND passord, instead the username only

Comment: We'd need to see the code in `program.c` (or whatever) to reproduce that.  Given `int main(void) { char buffer1[256] = ""; char buffer2[256] = ""; fgets(buffer1, sizeof(buffer1), stdin); fgets(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), stdin); buffer1[strcspn(buffer1, "\n")] = '\0'; buffer2[strcspn(buffer2, "\n")] = '\0'; printf("B1 [%s]\nB2 [%s]\n", buffer1, buffer2); return 0; }` (including `<stdio.h>` and `<string.h>`, of course), you should get the user name and password in the B1 and B2 output lines. If you don't, can you show a hex dump of (dummy) user name and password file that illustrates the problem?